# how to Convert Unstructured excel sheet Data into json object and to display in table format

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

i need to display unstructured excel data in table format along with space

now i am displaying the table for unstructured data but it is not taking space in columns, and table also in unstructured format

```
onFileChange(ev) {
    let workBook = null;
    let jsonData = null;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const file = ev.target.files[0];
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      const data = reader.result;
      workBook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
      jsonData = workBook.SheetNames.reduce((initial, name) => {
        const sheet = workBook.Sheets[name];
        initial[name] = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
        return initial;
      }, {});
      this.columnsArr = [];
      this.data = Object.keys(jsonData).map(key=>jsonData[key])
      console.log(this.data);
      this.data.forEach((elm, index) => {
        this.item = elm;
        for (var firstKey in this.item[0]) break;
          this.emtKey = firstKey;
      });

      // this.output = dataString.slice(0, 300);
      // this.setDownload(dataString);
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  }
```

i need to display the table has same as excel sheet data